# How to set anti aliasing option on SimpleRenderer

Tags: java, image-processing, ghostscript, ghost4j

I'm using Ghost4J SimpleRenderer to convert my PDF to Image. By default the output png image is not anti aliased.

How can i set it.?

I know that, using Core API we can do it. But, is there any way in High Level API, for setting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is simply not built in. Just look at the command line options that `SimpleRenderer` is using: http://ghost4j.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ghost4j/trunk/src/main/java/net/sf/ghost4j/renderer/SimpleRenderer.java?revision=143&view=markup

I would recommend to improve the `SimpleRenderer` with the options mentioned here http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Rendering_parameters

I think adding `"-dTextAlphaBits=4","-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4"` to `gsArgs` is enough.

Comment: thanx for the reply. let me look in to this :)

Comment: Thank you! I added an 'antialisating' parameter on SimpleRender to support that. It not released yet, but available in the snapshot version. Also note that Ghost4J has a new home : http://www.ghost4j.org and is now hosted on GitHub at : https://github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j